# Re: MapBox package Flutter: How should we wait/know if "onStyleLoadedCallback" is finished when initialising the map?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Map shows fine, but does not show marker.
When you add a new marker when map finished loading and idling, the marker shows.
When you add a delay to addSymbol inside "onMapCreated" like below, it then shows the symbol:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
              mapController.addSymbol(
                SymbolOptions(
                  geometry: LatLng(widget.post.lat, widget.post.long),
                  iconImage: "airport-15",
                  iconSize: 5,
                ),
              );
            });
```

How do we know or are suppose to handle the wait for onStyleCallBack?

This is the error that comes up when you don't add the delay:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager.create(java.util.List)' on a null object reference

Works perfectly on iOS without any delays.
Same behaviour on device and emulator.
Version: mapbox_gl: ^0.9.0

Code:

```
onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller) async {                
            controller.addSymbol(
              SymbolOptions(
                geometry: LatLng(widget.post.lat, widget.post.long),
                iconImage: "airport-15",
                iconSize: 5,
              ),
            );
          },
```

Full output:

```
E/MapboxMapBuilder(11157): setCameraTargetBounds is supported only after map initiated.
I/Mbgl-EGLConfigChooser(11157): In emulator: true
D/HostConnection(11157): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdfd4d000, enter code heretid 14985
D/HostConnection(11157): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0
D/EGL_emulation(11157): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdfd1aae0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc70ab560)
D/eglCodecCommon(11157): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(11157): eglCreateContext: 0xdfd1b740: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation(11157): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdfd1b740: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdfdc3920)
D/eglCodecCommon(11157): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 0
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager.create(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.onMethodCall(MapboxMapController.java:648)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/mapbox_maps_5(11157):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/flutter (11157): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager.create(java.util.List)' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.annotation.SymbolManager.create(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
E/flutter (11157):  at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.onMethodCall(MapboxMapController.java:648)
E/flutter (11157):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (11157):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (11157):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter (11157):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (11157):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter (11157):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/flutter (11157):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/flutter (11157):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (11157):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note: you should only add annotations (e.g. symbols or circles) after `onStyleLoadedCallback` has been called. So you should add symbols inside `onStyleLoadedCallback` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is later but I just wanna post answer because there are some few answers about it ...

Like Edwin Triviños says, you just need to set your callback on MapBox parameters and create a new function to do whatever you wanna do. For example, in my case:

Mapbox config:

```
return MapboxMap(
          accessToken: MapboxVariables.accessToken,
          styleString: "mapbox://styles/your-url-from-mapbox",
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoaded,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          trackCameraPosition: true,
          myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.Tracking,
          onUserLocationUpdated: (UserLocation userLocation){ 
             _movingCameraToLocation();
          },
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
            zoom: 11.0,
            ),
      );
```

As you can see, I'm calling `onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoaded,` as a callback. An after that just need a basic `_onStyleLoaded` function, like this:

```
void _onStyleLoaded() async {
    //your code 
}
```